# how to clear picaso cache images in android?

Tags: android

I have long list of image view. I use Picaso for loading images. I want to clear the picaso cache. it loads old images. I need to load refreshed images(new ones). I think it takes old images. How to do it? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
mPicasso.with(mContext)
    .load(url)
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE )
    .into(imageView);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to go to your phone settings and click "Clear Cache" and then reinstall the app